# Custom MKMapPin image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, dictionary

I just wanted to quickly ask how I could use an image as my MKMapPin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the viewForAnnotation method, create an MKAnnotationView (not an MKPinAnnotationView) and set its image property.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can subclass mkannotationview to add more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code to your viewForAnnotation message:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{   
    // ... get the annotation delegate and allocate the MKAnnotationView (annView)
    if ([annotationDelegate.type localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:@"needs_your_image"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image_here.png"];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
        [annView addSubview:imageView];
    }
    // ...
```